# how do i get jquery to work in joomla 3 with a template that has jquery already built in?

Tags: jquery, joomla

I've installed Joomla 3 and have the "[Gamers](http://www.shape5.com/demo/index.php?gamers)" template installed from Shape 5.

jQuery seems to be already loaded with this template but I can't get any jQuery script to work in a module.

I've tried using both $ and jQuery as I believe Joomla uses `jQuery` instead of `$` but no luck. I've also tried using the plugin to load jQuery no conflict from the Joomla Extentions Directory.

I'm trying something simple like below, does anyone have any suggestions on troubleshooting this?

```
<div id="div1">div1 contents</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none">div2 contents</div>
<button id="button">Button</button>

<div id="div3">div3 contents</div>
<div id="div4" style="display: none">div4 contents</div>
<button id="button2">Button</button>

<script>
        $('#button').on('click', function() {
        $('#div1').remove();
        $('#div2').show();
    });


    $('#button2').on('click', function() {
        $('#div3').html($('#div4').html());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where are you adding your script?

Comment: my web address if you want to take a look is here: http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com

Comment: i've tried loading the script in the module, and also in the head of the template

Comment: I un-tag `mootools` since I think this is not mootools related. Please pu it back if you feel i did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nice situation here.

These are the three copies of jQuery you're loading:

- jQuery 1.6.2 from cdn
- jQuery 1.8.1 with custom prefix by jomsocial;
- jQuery 1.10.2 in /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js

Until you remove the duplicates (not jomsocial, that has a different prefix, so it won't cause errors, just waste of bandwidth) you won't get any scripts to work.

Then you have several noConflicts. Mootools which you don't need.

This is the list of scripts on your site: the only one that's loaded thoughtfully is the jquery-ui, there's a check to avoid reloading it accidentally.

```
<script src="/media/system/js/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/calendar-setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/components/com_community/assets/joms.jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/modules/mod_s5_box/js/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
if(jQuery.easing.easeOutExpo==undefined){
document.write('<script src="http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/templates/gamers/js/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>');
}
//]]></script>
```

then inside the `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="http://v80.undergroundsoundz.com/modules/mod_s5_accordion_menu/js/s5_accordion_menu_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

**To start with,** 
I suggest you make a backup.  Then find the jQuery 1.6. and get rid of that one.

The output is:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it should be inserted with something like

```
$document->addScript("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js");
```

Hopefully it should be in your template's `index.php`.  Or, if the developers were thoughtful, you might even find an option to disable it in the template configuration.  If it's not in the template, run:

```
grep -rL "ajax.googleapis" *
```

in a shell in your site root.

Then try to remove some of the `noConflict`.

Comment: so are you suggesting that the only way round is to edit the core files to remove these duplicates in head and body?

Comment: I improved the answer. You might get away with a template option or a simple 1-line edit of your template

Comment: many thanks for your help, after disabling a few javascript options in the template backend, and disabling the plugin as suggested this started working :)

Answer (score 1):

In your module, use the following to automatically get your script to append to the head of the template:

```
<?php
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration("
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#button').on('click', function() {
          $('#div1').remove();
          $('#div2').show();
       });
       $('#button2').on('click', function() {
          $('#div3').html($('#div4').html());
       });
   });
");
?>
```

I would also recommend disabling the **jqueryintegrator** as this seems to be importing a file noConflict"" that is already handled by Joomla 3.x. I believe it is also importing another copy of jQuery. Your JomSocial is also importing yet another copy of jQuery (making that 3 in total), however the only way to prevent this is to edit the core files.

Comment: Since it is likely running in noConflict mode  (since there are so many noconflict.js files...) I would do `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...` to make sure that you get the jQuery object.

Comment: tried the suggestion above which is on the link now but still no luck :(

Comment: @DanBrad - I've inspected your site with Firebug and I can't find this code in the head at all. Are you sure you have added it to the module?